# ArcGIS Server 10.3.1 WMS Property "online-resource" not synchronised in Manager

Tags: arcgis-server, wms, arcgis-10.3

I have a reverse-proxy set up to access my ArcGIS for Server 10.3.1 from the internet. After creating the wms service in ArcGIS Server Manager I can edit the wms service properties e.g Name, Title, Description, Keywords, Online-Resource etc

The Property "Online Resource" is always automatically filled out with the server address, but due to the reverse proxy this property needs to be changed so that the service works properly on the web. For example a wms service in ArcGIS Online will not be displayed until I modify the "Online Resource" property to include the external domain and not the internal server name.

ArcGIS Server Manager does not however save this property after it is modified - thus forcing me to use an external GetCapabilities which is very irritating and time consuming.

Is this a bug? Is it the same for everyone? or is there a logic there which I can´t see?

Comment: Is this a results of not updating the "WebContextURL" parameter?